# What might be an effective mode of transportation for Giants?

Tags: physics, fantasy-races, vehicles

In my story [Giants](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/171445/what-environment-would-giants-be-best-adapted-for/171448#171448), humans, and a bunch of other [fantasy races](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/168595/why-would-humans-be-the-dominant-species) live along side each other and i'm curious as to what might be an effective mode of transportation for 10 foot tall Giants with Ancient Greek level technology? now these giant aren't just proportionally scaled up human having several adaptations to cope with there height with the [How to make a realistic 'giant'](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/8569/how-to-make-a-realistic-giant/8582#85) best explaining them.

Note: magic does not exist in my story

Comment: Roller Skates, everyone knows giants love roller skates, they build special roads for them.

Comment: As opposed to the same transportation everyone else used? The only thing Giants can't do is ride horses but walking and carts should work.

Comment: wow.   Just Wow.   - And it's not the good kind.

Comment: What equivalent transportation do the other sizes of humanoid have available to them? "Greek level" ... meaning "Ancient Greece"?, because I know for a fact Greeks these days almost always use cars or public transport. Not donkeys.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're talking about long distance travel, **ships, boats, or canal-barges** are a good choice. Even today, watercraft carry humanity's heaviest cargo items and even at rather primitive levels of technology, crafting a watercraft capable of carrying an extra-large humanoid is completely feasible.

In fact, this could add an interesting dimension to your setting: Due to the giant's inability to cross long distances quickly on land or forming mobile land armies (no horses or wagons), their culture has evolved sea-fairing, archipelago-living, and coastal raiding characteristics.

Answer (score 8):

## Mammoths

Because I found these images in Reddit and Pinterest while typing *giant riding mammoth* in Google Images.

[image: Giant riding mammoth][image: Giant riding mammoth]